# Why is REST considered more scalable than soap?

Tags: rest

I have been trying to understand REST and scalability is one feature which is mentioned more often when compared with webservices .

Could someone please explain why is REST considered more scalable than soap ?

Comment: WCF, one implentation of soap, even supports stateful exchanges. That alone causes the # of possible concurrent user to drop. XML as a format requires more memory to process than JSON. SOAP is like a million features implemented on top of HTTP (and sometimes other transports). REST is just HTTP and leans heavily on features already in the spec. HTTP has built into the idea of caches, a central server can serve a lot of users if those users don't even hit the central server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is considered more scalable. I have never heard that before. It probably scales just as well or bad as a REST design. If properly designed it should scale horizontally just fine.

One thing most people agree about though, is that it is considered simpler because the building blocks are simpler. Basic HTTP messages and usually JSON, instead of complicated and large XML-based standards-based methods of transferring data and making RPC-style calls.

Comment: Any of those "simpler" aspects should always be _measured_ before being taken as given. Some of them might not matter in a particular environment, or might even lean in the direction of SOAP.